# NN for resource management of an VM

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, references, estimators

Are there any papers/projects that deal with neural networks learning/adaptation for resource management (learning of system behavior and resource adaptation such as memory, CPU for an VM)?

e.g. some logs are being observed by an NN that classify whether more resources are needed for the next particular time interval.

Maybe you have an advice to above-written scenario and can give some tips on such points as and more:

- which type of model should be taken
- how to collect and preprocess data (system logs)
- other challenges etc.

thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "resource management"?

Comment: @Tim resources such as memory, CPU etc in an VM

Comment: Could you add some context? Let's say that an algorithm looks at current memory usage and when it increases, it also increases the available memory, when it drops, it decreases it--this can be done (and is done) using simple heuristics. Where exactly would you see the place for ML in here? What scenarios do you have in mind?

Comment: @Tim this is the exact scenario that you described. I thought about a rule learning (which would represent you mentioned heuristics) but thought that eventually there are more intelligent approaches based on NNs